# web service (asmx) over ssl using C#

Tags: service, web

I have a web application calling various web services. Currently I do not have any ssl connection. I would like to use ssl.

My question is which way is best to use ssl
1. whenever the request comes, is it better to authenicate the credentials aganist client?
or
 2. Once authenicate the ceredential and use in subsequest web service calls

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember asmx web services are stateless, so you can try to create a login method wich can return a secure token encrypted using md5 or any cryptographic algorithm and pass that token in your methods there are various secure algorithms that you can take a look, theres no need to ask for a login and password in each method, you can consider to implement and expiration policy over the auth token as well.

regarding to the ssl you can configure only at the login method I think theres no need for the subsecuent methods.

there's another way you can do it you can implement HMAC you can generate it just one time then you can attach the HMAC signature to the request and validate that request, you need to save that computed sigature if the signature computed by the server matches the on the message it means that the message is authorized.

for more info you can take a look to [this article](http://www.piotrwalat.net/hmac-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api/) and i think is applicable to aspx web services